# PHP. Catching only numbers from a string

Tags: php, string, variables, numbers, int

If I have a string like

> $var = "adf91uaj19jj99877ad009";

Which is the easiest way to get all integers from this variable and create a new one? At this case

> $newVar= "911999877009";

Comment: Have you tried to search for an answer on this topic and you didn't stumbled upon [filter_var](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like pounding in a nail with a sledge hammer. Replace all non-digit characters (`\D`) with nothing (`''`).

```
$newVar = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $var);
```

Comment: The `g` flag only applies to JavaScript regexes, not PHP. Removed it for you.

Answer (score 4):

You can try

```
$var = "adf91uaj19jj99877ad009";
$var = filter_var($var,FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

Output

```
string '911999877009' (length=12)
```